# How to decode a DAT file in python?

Tags: python, read-write, file-read

I'm trying to read bytes from a DAT file. I know the data is supposed to be in either Binary or Hex. But when I try to read the bytes it prints out weird symbols. I'm assuming they are ascii values. I tried converting them but I keep getting the error message that 'str' cannot be converted. Does anyone know how I can decode it? And is read() the correct function to use for this?

```
import time
import binascii
import csv
import serial

with open('Example CARESCAPE Datalog.dat') as binary_file:
    for num in range(1,10):
        data = binary_file.readline()
        print(data)
```

[Here is the link to a screenshot of the weird symbols I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWnvj.png)

Comment: A binary file will not have any useful notion of linebreaks. So `readline()` will not work as expected.

Comment: To my understanding, that's not entirely true (though you're right that it may be misleading): https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline

Comment: Ya lutz you are right. I changed it to read() to get the individual bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.dat` file is not text, you should open it as a binary file with `'rb'` (per [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)):

```
with open('Example CARESCAPE Datalog.dat', 'rb') as binary_file:
```

You'll have to decode the bytes yourself:

**Note:**
Files opened in binary mode (including 'rb' in the mode argument) return contents as bytes objects without any decoding.

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me. Changed it to
with open('Example CARESCAPE Datalog.dat', 'rb') as binary_file: