# Python read hex data in to ASCII file

Tags: python, hex, ascii, transform

I got a "*.txt" files that can directly open as text or binary. data recorded in the file as follows:

```
"24 47 4E 47 47 41 2C 31 35 33 34 34 32 2E 30 30 30 2C 33 31 20 33 2E 35 31 37 36 2C 4E 2C 31 32 31 32 33 2E 30 35 33 36 2C 45 2C 31 2C 30 36 2C 34 2E 39 34 30 33 37 30 2C 32 32 2E 39 39 35 35 33 35 2C 4D 2C 2C 4D 2C 2C 2A 37 33 0D 0A 24 47 4E"
```

Each one actually is a char presented by hex. For example "24" is ASCII "#", "47" is ASCII "G". How can I directly transform the file into an ASCII text file in Python?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329010/how-to-decode-a-dat-file-in-python

Comment: I have tried that one. But it not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [chr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) function to convert an integer value (Unicode code point) to a character:

```
>>> string = "24 47 4E 47 47 41 2C 31 35 33 34 34 32 2E 30 30 30 2C 33 31 20 33 2E 35 31 37 36 2C 4E 2C 31 32 31 32 33 2E 30 35 33 36 2C 45 2C 31 2C 30 36 2C 34 2E 39 34 30 33 37 30 2C 32 32 2E 39 39 35 35 33 35 2C 4D 2C 2C 4D 2C 2C 2A 37 33 0D 0A 24 47 4E"
>>> "".join([chr(int(c, 16)) for c in string.split()])
    '$GNGGA,153442.000,31 3.5176,N,12123.0536,E,1,06,4.940370,22.995535,M,,M,,*73\r\n$GN'
```

Comment: thanks. I just figure out : 
[bytes().fromhex(i).decode('ascii') for i in the_bytes]
but it is not simplify as your solution.